# Declaring RLMArray property when using Realm Objective-C from Swift

Tags: swift, realm

```
class Post: RLMObject {
    var images: RLMArray!
    override init(JSON:json) {
        if let imagesArray = dictionary["images"].arrayObject {
            let imagesItems = RLMArray(objectClassName: StringObject.className())
            for dic in imagesArray {
                let image = StringObject(stringValue: dic as! String)
                imagesItems.addObject(image)
            }
            images = imagesItems
        }
    }
}
```

The code above I try to init `PostModel` include images property, but it alway crash in my project with:

> '(null)' is not supported as an RLMArray object type. RLMArrays can only contain instances of RLMObject subclasses

I saw in the documentation for Realm Swift to use `List<Foo>` to declare the array property, but I don't know how to do so in my case.

Comment: You should always use latest version of Realm, now it is 0.97.0   and refer their latest docs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using Realm's Objective-C API from Swift, array properties should be declared with a default value that is an instance of `RLMArray` with the appropriate object class name. For instance:

```
class Post: RLMObject {
    dynamic var images = RLMArray(objectClassName: StringObject.className())

    // …
}
```

Note also the presence of the `dynamic` modifier. This is required to ensure that accesses of the property are dispatched dynamically to the getters and setters for the property that `RLMObject` creates.